# Ubuntu in VM. Blackscreen after login

Tags: boot, virtualbox, login

I'm running Ubuntu 20.10 in Oracle VM on a win 7 PC. It boots just fine but after I log in the screen just goes black and stays black until I shut it off. I've had the same problem in the past but the problem has always solved it self after restarting the VM. This is however not the case now, it will always give me a blackscreen after I log in.

**VM specs:**

- 2048 MB RAM (Out of a total 8192 MB, and yes I've made sure I've got enough free RAM)
- 64 MB Video memory (Out of a total 128 MB)
- 100 GB disc
- Graphics controller is VMSVGA with 3D acceleration

I have not changed any of these settings since I created the VM and it has worked just fine in the past.

Edit: I tried changing my graphics controller to VBoxVGA and turning off 3D acceleration, which solved the problem, but now the performance is worse.

Answer (score 0):

As you already experienced, you had to disable advanced graphic virtualization.

Now that you have working VM, look for Oracle support docs, and find VM driver packages. Most well known hypervisors have some way of supporting some of most popular OS versions.

I am (was?)  a bit confused by Oracle, but since Win 7 is mentioned as host, I assume we're talking about VirtualBox.

In that case install this inside Ubuntu VM:

sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso

It's set of tools to help host and guest... Get along better.

After install and a reboot (to check if you see any improvements), you can try enabling 3D acceleration again.

In any case, these additional tools will help you with more than just graphics.

Edit: official docs nkw VirtualBox was confirmed:
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html

Once virtualbox additions are installed you get an ISO in VM. Then you need to mount ISO (either inside VM, or through the host and VirtualBox GUI), and install packages from mounted device.

ISO will install in the directory `/usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso`

Comment: Well guest additions are already installed.

Comment: See if you can find latest Oracle's ISO on their website. And make sure to mount iso and install the packages from it! See my updated answer